# Organize C functions with different core specific implementations

Tags: c

I wonder if there is any good way forward to handle the following topic.

I write libraries in C which usually use plain C code and some core specific instructions (not for each function, but to optimize).
Recently we introduced a new core to our environment where some of the instructions from the previous core are not available.

To use my existing libraries I would need to re-write these functions by either replace the core specific instructions with plain C code or replace the core specific instructions with the ones from the new core.

This brought me to think about how to organize such a library that shall support functions with:

- plain C Code (ANSI C Code)
- Core specific C code (for different cores)

I was thinking about the following solutions:

**1. Adding a compile switch**

This is the most straigth-forward solution, as you can easily switch between functionallity and by default you can always fall back to plain C code implementations.

Example:

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    #if CORE_A
        return CORE_A_ADD(x, y);
    #elif CORE_B
        return CORE_B_ADD(x, y);
    #else
        return (x + y)
    #endif
 }
```

Thats actually not too bad, but usually this makes the code pretty hard to read.

**2. Add a dedicated C file for each implementation**

Another option I was thinking is to add a seperate C file for each core.

```
File: add.c

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x+y);
    }

 File: add_core_A.c

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        CORE_A_ADD(x, y);
    }

 File: add_core_B.c

    int add(int x, int y)
    {
        CORE_B_ADD(x, y);
    }
```

The makefile then can decided during compilation which C file is going to be used.
This has the advantage that the implementation per core is seperated in dedicated files. Furthermore its cool for testing as you can check the core specific implementation vs plain C implementation.
Once you have finished the plain C version of a function, you might copy this into the core specific implementations first before you start optimization.

**3. Use the extern C file function as wrapperr**

This approach is similiar to option 2, but does not require to have seperate C files (but can be).
The public function simply wraps the call to a local function with the specific implementation.

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    #if CORE_A
        return add_func_CORE_A(x, y);
    #elif CORE_B
        return add_func_CORE_B(x, y);
    #else
        return add_func_C(x,y)
    #endif
 }

 static int add_func_C(x, y)
 {
     return (x + y)
 }

 static int add_func_CORE_A(x,y)
 {
     return add_CORE_A(x, y);
 }

 static int add_func_CORE_B(x,y)
 {
     return add_CORE_B(x, y);
 }
```

Probably there are much more solutions available. So I would be interested if there are good practices how to organize such a structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this a bit off topic and opinion based? But nonetheless I would go with the second method, or have a seperate Project for each "core" and only share plain C implementation and header files between the projects. I don't think the header should "choose" which c file should be compiled but the make- or cmake-file should determine that.

Comment: Or I would rather choose in the C file via `#ifdef` which core-implementation file should be included

Comment: I have had to use each approach in various circumstances. I would not expect there to be a one-size fits all solution. Write your code as suits you, but keep it well organized and documented so that you can easily change from one approach to another when the need arises.

Comment: micro optimizations are NOT a good idea.  Much better to write all library functions in plain C.  If you really want to micro optimize (after completing the plain C code and need some key area speed up, Then use some tracing tool to determine exactly what is taking all the time.  I.E. premature optimizations are a waste of time and resources